# Data not showing on template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is the first time I'll be implementing a Class Based View on a real project but the data is not showing on the template.

```
        <div class="container">
          <h4 class="heading-decorated text-center mt-5">Our Volunteers</h4>
          {% for volunteer in volunteers %}
          <div class="row row-30 text-center mb-5">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
              <figure class="box-icon-image"><a href="#"><img class="rounded" src="{{volunteer.volunteer_image.url}}" alt="" width="126" height="102"/></a></figure>
                <p class="lead">{{volunteers.volunteer_name}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

views.py

```
class VolunteerListView(ListView):
    model = Volunteers
    context_object_name = 'volunteer'
    template_name = 'add_my_language/home.html'
```

models.py

```
class Volunteers(models.Model):
    volunteer_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/volunteers')
    volunteer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.volunteer_name
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my models for the homepage was separate hence the data was not showing. Once I combined all the models for the homepage, my answer above worked.

Answer (score -1):

> While this view is executing, self.object_list will contain the list of objects (usually, but not necessarily a queryset) that the view is operating upon.

**ListView :**

```
class VolunteerListView(ListView):

    model = Volunteers

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       # extra context goes here
       return context
```

**Template**

```
<h1>Volunteers</h1>

   {% for volunteer in object_list %}
     <p class="lead">{{volunteers.volunteer_name}}</p>

   {% endfor %}
```

**Further reading**

[Generic display views Official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)